# Angular2. How to unit test a component with dynamically created html

Tags: unit-testing, angular

I have created a virtual list component, where I only render the visible lines.
When creating unit tests, I can test the view while adding elements, but when I remove or change elements then the 'fixture.debugElement' still returns the previous count.

I have created this small test component which shows the problem

The component

```
class TestComponent {
    @ViewChild('view') view: ElementRef;
    constructor(public ngRenderer: Renderer) {
    }
    public add(text: string): void {
        let parentelm = this.view.nativeElement;
        let element = this.ngRenderer.createElement(parentelm, 'div');
        this.ngRenderer.setText(element, text);
    }
    public remove(index: number): void {
        let elm: HTMLElement = this.view.nativeElement;
        let child = elm.children[index];
        elm.removeChild(child);
    }
}
```

and the test

```
describe('test component', () => {
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;
    let component: TestComponent;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [TestComponent],
        });
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });
    it('add and remove divs', () => {
        component.add('item1');
        component.add('item2');
        let content = fixture.debugElement.query( (elm: DebugElement) => { return elm.attributes['id'] === 'list'; });
        expect(content.children.length).toBe(2);
        component.add('item3');
        expect(content.children.length).toBe(3); // <-- this works
        component.remove(1);
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(content.children.length).toBe(2); // <-- this fails
    });
});
```

When checking the browser, then of course the view only contains 'item1' and 'item3'

How can I force an update of the debug element ?

Edit:
I see the fixture contains the native element. 
If I add this

```
    let elm = <HTMLElement>fixture.elementRef.nativeElement;
    console.log(elm.innerHTML);
```

Then I see the correct html

```
'<div id="list"><div>item1</div><div>item3</div></div>'
```

So maybe the solution is to iterate native elements instead of using the debugElement ?

Comment: Oddd... I tested it and it looks like some magic voodoo

Comment: Native element works though `fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#list');`

Comment: `expect(content.childNodes.length).toBe(2);` assuming `content ` is reassigned to the above statement

Comment: yes, working with nativeElement works. I have started writing my unit test using native instead of debugElm. But I would still assume debugElm should work, why else provide it. Anyway. I can continue on my unit tests using nativeElm.